# setting up a hierarchy for a query in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy

I am attempting to set up a query that will return records following a certain hierarchy.  My code thus far returns one record from groups where the count =2 where my water value is not equal to 7. If there are no records that match this criteria, I need it to look in the 'earth' field, and return values within the same table that = 'Y'.  I'm relatively new to SQL, so any help you guys can give is appreciated

```
select  collection, id
from TABLE a
where a.collection in (
    select collection
    from TABLE a
    where to_number(substr(collection 10,3)) =2
    group by collection
    having  max(water) <> min(water)
    and min(water) = '01')
and water <> '07';
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Without knowing how your tables are setup this is going to be tough to answer.  If you could create a SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) that sets up the table and seeds some data then someone can update that fiddle with the answer.

Comment: Atleast ask question that is comprehensible. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask